# How to Prevent Lag from Javascript Adjusting Width

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am following this tutorial: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_overlay. However, when I do its overlay animation, Firefox makes the animation seem pretty laggy — I think this might be because I have a lot of other animated elements. Note: this does not occur in Safari or Google Chrome.

What can I do to make the animation smoother for Firefox?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.overlay {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.9);
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.overlay-content {
  position: relative;
  top: 25%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.overlay a {
  padding: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.overlay a:hover, .overlay a:focus {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.overlay .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 45px;
  font-size: 60px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .overlay a {font-size: 20px}
  .overlay .closebtn {
  font-size: 40px;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myNav" class="overlay">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <div class="overlay-content">
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Services</a>
    <a href="#">Clients</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>

<h2>Fullscreen Overlay Nav Example</h2>
<p>Click on the element below to open the fullscreen overlay navigation menu.</p>
<p>In this example, the navigation menu will slide in, from left to right:</p>
<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>

<script>
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "100%";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "0%";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What version of firefox are you using? I used your code and tested with the latest version and there is no lag.

Comment: Mine too, not a single lag.

Comment: I'm using the latest Firefox 68.0.1. The demo website does not have lag, but when I put it on the website I'm currently developing, there is quite a bit of lag. It's weird... I have other more intensive animations that don't have lag.

Comment: So I realize it only really lags on my intro-section page, which has an animated canvas (which might be the reason for why it lags?). But it works decently if I scroll down to my text sections. Any insights?

Comment: There's also more considerable lag when I make the overlay transparent, versus when it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

This animation is very simple and light, therefore, it should not cause lag for most users.

It modifies the DOM with the `HTMLElement.style` property, which is the simplest way to change DOM elements properties.

Since you are encoutering some lags, instead of changing the code, you should try [**clearing the Firefox cache as explained here**](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-clear-firefox-cache).

Comment: Clearing the cache did not work, but thanks for the suggestion.